# find out word frequency in a table according to a list

Tags: r, list

Now I have a dtm, so I turn the dtm as a frequency table

```
freqs <- as.data.frame(inspect(dtm1))
```

Here's how freqs looks like, it contains one row shows the frequency of these words in a document

```
I    really   hate   school   how   can  are  you  hi
4      5        3       2      3     1    4    5   1
```

I have a list

```
list <- c("hi", "how", "are", "you")
```

How can I find out the frequency of words in the frequency table according to the list, then compile these word frequencies in a table

```
hi  how  are  you
1    3    4   5
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post.

Comment: If `dtm1` is a vector of strings, then simply do `table(dtm1)[list]`

Comment: dtm is a document term matrix

Comment: How about `freqs[list]` then?

Answer (score 1):

If the words are the variable names in the `data.frame`

```
> freqs[,list]
  hi how are you
1  1   3   4   5
```

Comment: hmm, I use this code but only see the words, without the frequency number

Comment: @Lucia, this is strange, isn't that the words are variable names for freqs?

Comment: hi, it's this one freqs[list]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

## Using `table()`:

```
words <- "hi how are you doing today I really hate school and I want to quit how can you still go to school"
lst <- c("hi", "how", "are", "you")
table(strsplit(words, split=" "))[lst]
hi how are you 
1   2   1   2
```

## Working with `data.frame()`:

```
df <- as.data.frame(table(strsplit(words,split=" ")))
colnames(df) <- c("words","freqs")
df[df$words%in%lst,]
   words freqs
2    are     1
7     hi     1
8    how     2
17   you     2
```